# Is this expected behaviour of the MVC IDependencyResolver?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have implemented a System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver which looks up services registered with Castle Windsor. My GetService(Type serviceType) implementation is below (for MVC3 RC2).

```
public object GetService(Type serviceType)
{
    object service = null;
    try
    {
        service = _container.Resolve(serviceType);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Warn("Could not resolve service-type {0} via {1}", 
            serviceType.Name, _resolverName);
    }

    return service;
}
```

This works well, but I have a question about warnings that I see in my logs (I log all exceptions as 'Warn' - see the code above):

```
WARN  Default [] - Could not resolve service-type Index_cshtml via
    WindsorDependencyResolver
WARN  Default [] - Could not resolve service-type RegistrationForm_cshtml via
    WindsorDependencyResolver
WARN  Default [] - Could not resolve service-type LoginForm_cshtml via
    WindsorDependencyResolver
```

These are *views*. Is this expected behaviour? If so, why is the dependency resolver asked to find views? If not, what should I be doing to resolve this?

Note that I haven't registered an instance of IViewPageActivator (see the warning, below) which should signal to the framework that views should be resolved in the default manner. Why do I still see requests for views through my dependency resolver?

```
WARN  Default [] - Could not resolve service-type IViewPageActivator via 
    WindsorDependencyResolver
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDependencyResolver in MVC3 could resolve views as well as other types. This could be very useful in case when you need to change view implementations for example when you are unit-testing your solution.
More details: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt11-view-page-activator.html:

> The logic in BuildManagerCompiledView
>   consults the dependency resolver,
>   calling
>   GetSerivce(typeof(IViewPageActivator))
>   and using the provided service when
>   present. If there is no
>   IViewPageActivator present in the
>   dependency resolver, we will then ask
>   the dependency resolver to create the
>   concrete view page type by calling
>   GetService(viewPageType). If the
>   dependency resolver also fails to
>   create the concrete view page type, we
>   finally fall back to the MVC 2
>   behavior of using
>   Activator.CreateInstance to create the
>   view page type.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I'm aware of this - what I didn't mention in my post is that I haven't registered an IViewPageActivator with Windsor so when the call comes for this type my DependencyResolver returns null, which should signal to the framework that it should go back to the default way of resolving views. That's why I don't understand why I see these calls to resolve views.

Comment: Read carefully: If there is no IViewPageActivator present in the dependency resolver, we will then ask the dependency resolver to create the concrete view page type by calling GetService(viewPageType)

Comment: Ooops. Sloppy of me. OK - so the behaviour is expected. Now, I don't need a special IViewPageActivator. I'm happy with the default behaviour. Should I just leave things as they are (and continue to ignore the unresolved views) or should I be doing something else?

Comment: You could ignore `IView` implementations in your resolver if you are absolutely sure, that it should be ignored. It will improve performance.

Comment: Good call. Thanks for your help.